# What's the difference between "hook and "peg" in this case?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between the two when talking about hanging a jacket?

Example sentence:

> He stomped to the front door and snatched his parka from its hook/peg.

[jacket from its hook](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%20jacket%20from%20its%20hook%22&client=ubuntu&sxsrf=ALeKk00rZjm2cu443fAvM5_ZHN_uY6WxZA:1589802077543&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHgOGgqr3pAhXGEqYKHcLcA1AQ_AUoAXoECAYQCQ&biw=1855&bih=984) has 764 results on Google Books.

[jacket from its peg](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk0007OFoq2eLJrpW2nnJDw2sKjfMTQ%3A1589802079974&ei=X3TCXrL6OuabmAWjjZzoBg&q=%22%20jacket%20from%20its%20peg%22&oq=%22%20jacket%20from%20its%20peg%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...33478.34229.0.34330.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.9-8TdR6YW7M) has 367 results on Google Books.

Comment: In practice, what some people call a ***clothes hook*** could be exactly the same as something that others might call a ***clothes peg*** (but bear in mind the latter can also mean the clip used to hang laundry on a drying- / washing-line, which the former can't). But you've only got to consider the "base" definition of the word ***hook*** to see it implies a ***curved*** "pin", which ***peg*** doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are coat pegs:

[image]

These are coat hooks:

[image]